# Display name in plotly boxplot if using q1/median/q3

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot, plotly-python

I'm using plotly in python to create a boxplot. I want to display the name at the y axis.

[Here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/box/#box-name) it's written, I can't set the y and y0 as I have not done. But how to set the y axis to categorial? The following code does not help:

```
fig.update_yaxes(type='category')
```

Here's the whole code:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Box(
   name="TestName",
   q1=[ 1 ], median=[ 4], q3=[ 7 ], 
   orientation="h"))

fig.update_yaxes(type='category')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Did you try `fig.update_traces(yaxis=<VALUE>, selector=dict(type='box'))` from [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/box/#box-yaxis)?

Comment: But what must be the <VALUE>? This didn't work for me: {'type': 'category'},

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to metion you @mosc9575

Comment: By dafault and only one y-axis it is `y`.

Comment: @mosc9575 Unfortunately it didn't work. 
Before and after the update_yaxes and without that.